# i need a library on iOS to make a Microsoft directLine-botframework client

Tags: ios, websocket, direct-line-botframework, socketrocket

has anyone used the SocketRocket library on iOS to make a Microsoft directLine-botframework client? I have tried it but the result is empty. If someone has made a Microsoft directLine-botframework client for iOS, I would like to know what library to use. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

The problem was not from the SocketRocket library, the problem is that directLine only uses communication with websockets to respond, requests must be made with HTTP.